# Check boxes in table for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

I want to fill a table with rows of Questions. Then have a checkbox as a column to select the Question to submit in my form. I have a collection_check_boxes, not sure how to put them in the table where the :question_ids will be selectable.

The form:

```
<%= form_for(@test) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question %><br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :question_ids, Question.all.to_a.collect, :id, :content, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
  </div>

  <div id="container" style="width:1100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <button type="button" class="reset">Reset Search</button>
  <table width="100%" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="2%" class="filter-false">CHECKBOX Header</th>
    <th width="40%" data-placeholder="Search">Content</th>
    <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">Type</th>
    <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">Category</th>
    <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">Product</th>
    <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">User</th>
    <th width="8%" data-placeholder="Search">Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody>
<%# f.Question.all. ? do |q| %>
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
  <tr>
    <td><% q.check_box_tag %></td>
    <td><%= q.content %></td>
    <td><%= q.question_type %></td>
    <td><%= q.category %></td>
    <td><%= q.Product.find(product_id).name %></td>
    <td><%= q.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= q.active %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Create Test", id: "commit" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What type of object is @test?

Comment: @test = Test.new(test_params)

Comment: lols.  Ok, substitute 'test' for 'foo' in my answer then.

Comment: Okay, I will trys it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other field helpers are going to produce inputs whose name is like `name="foo[name]"`, `name="foo[type]"`, etc.  You need to send through an array of question_ids as the value of `"foo[question_ids]"`.  I've used `foo` here because i don't know what the class of your @test object is.

I would remove the `collection_check_boxes` you have there already (ie remove the following):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :question %><br>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :question_ids, Question.all.to_a.collect, :id, :content, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
</div>
```

Then, in the part where you're iterating over the questions, with one row per question, change your `check_box_tag` to

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "foo[question_ids][]", q.id, @test.question_ids.include?(q.id) %></td>
```

Because of the "[]" at the end of the input's name attribute, all the values of the checked checkboxes will be combined into a single array in params[:foo][:question_ids], and will thus set up the question associations when the controller calls

```
@foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
```

Comment: What would I put where <% @questions.each do |q| %> is to relate to the form_for f ?

Comment: That's not a very good English sentence, so i'm not sure what you mean, but you don't need to use `f` all the way through the form.  You can make your own _tag helpers whenever you want.  `f` is just a shortcut but sometimes it's simpler to do it yourself with a _tag.

Comment: I get this error: undefined local variable or method `question' for #<#<Class:0x007f8e49479508>:0x007f8e49426e20>

Comment: I beg your pardon, i just noticed that you're using `q` as the loop variable, not `question`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I also updated it to check whether that question is selected already (the third argument should evaluate to true or false, to determine whether the checkbox is checked already)

Comment: No errors, I just don't have the check_box now. Not sure what to put in the header, or make the check box show up

Comment: Whoops, i put it in a `<% %>` tag instead of `<%= %>`, so it's not being rendered out.  I will fix my answer (again), but you should be able to diagnose this sort of minor error yourself.

Comment: This is true, I actually just did, but thank you for your thoroughness